# Check position with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say i have html structure like this:
How can I make a check something like this with jquery: if **"tab2"** is before **"tab3 Active"** do something... And if **"tab2"** is after **"tab3 Active"** do something else? 

Thank you guys!!!

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

 <ul class="Mytabs">
 <li class="tab1"></li>
 <li class="tab2"></li>
 <li class="tab3 Active"></li>
 <li class="tab4"></li>
 <li class="tab5"></li>

 </ul>
```

Comment: why are you performing this type of check? It may be that we could suggest a better technique for what you are attempting?

Comment: I am creating a slideshow with Jquery and I need to check my image position i relation to the "Active" element (is it before or after " Active")....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `prev()` and `next()` to check to see where the element is in relation to another. Try this:

```
var $tab = $(".tab2");
if ($tab.prev(".active").length) {
    // tab2 is after the active tab
}
else if ($tab.next(".active").length) {
    // tab2 is before the active tab
}
```

Using this method you an easily change the tab you want to inspect, and it doesn't matter which tab has the `active` class on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.tab2 + .tab3.Active').length) { /* do something */ }


if ($('.tab3.Active + .tab2').length) { /* do something else */ }
```

You can just use the adjacent selector (`+`)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
if ($('.tab2').next().hasClass('tab3')) {
   // tab2 before tab3
} else {
   // tab3 before tab2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".tab2").parent().children().index(".tab2") < $(".tab3").parent().children().index(".tab3")) {
}
else {
}
```